# Undefined Index when site moved from Apashe to IIS Server

Tags: php, indexing, undefined

I developped a PHP website on an Apashe Server who worked just fine. When moved to my client's IIS Server we have a lot of errors like this one :

```
[18-May-2017 16:35:15 Asia/Kuwait] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: coupon in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\tourdesoceans\ville.php on line 61
```

I understand the error and checked the variables using isset(), !empty(), var_dump() and using $_GET instead of $_POST and they all seem to return expected results.

Here's a part of the form I'm using (I shortened it for this post) :

```
<form class="inscription" method="post">
    <a href="/">Choisissez une autre ville</a>
    <h1>ÉVÈNEMENT <?php echo $data['ville']; ?></h1>
    <p><strong>RÉSERVÉ AUX PROFESSIONNELS</strong></p>
    <p class="vip"><strong>Vous disposez d'une invitation VIP ?</strong><br />
    Merci de renseigner le code présent sur votre coupon :<br />
    <input type="text" name="coupon" value="<?php echo $_POST['coupon']; ?>" />
    <?php echo $erreur; ?></p>

    <label>Agence de voyage* :</label>
    <input type="text" name="agence" value="<?php echo $_POST['agence']; ?>" required />

    <label>Nom* :</label>
    <input type="text" name="nom" value="<?php echo $_POST['nom']; ?>" required />

    <label>Prénom* :</label>
    <input type="text" name="prenom" value="<?php echo $_POST['prenom']; ?>" required />

    <label>Email* :</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $_POST['email']; ?>" required />

    <label>Téléphone* :</label>
    <input type="tel" name="telephone" pattern="^((\+\d{1,3}(-| )?\(?\d\)?(-| )?\d{1,5})|(\(?\d{2,6}\)?))(-| )?(\d{3,4})(-| )?(\d{4})(( x| ext)\d{1,5}){0,1}$" value="<?php echo $_POST['telephone']; ?>" required />

    <label>Adresse professionnelle* :</label>
    <textarea name="adresse" required><?php echo $_POST['adresse']; ?></textarea>

    <label>Code postal* :</label>
    <input type="text" name="cpostal" value="<?php echo $_POST['cpostal']; ?>" required />

    <label>Ville* :</label>
    <input type="text" name="ville" value="<?php echo $_POST['ville']; ?>" required />

    <input type="hidden" name="lieu" value="<?php echo strtolower($_POST['id']);?>" required />

    <input type="submit" value="Valider ma demande d’inscription" />
    <p>Si vous ne disposez pas d'une invitation VIP, <strong>rendez-vous le 1er juin 2017 pour vous inscrire !</strong></p>
    <p class="mention">*Champs obligatoires</p>
</form>
```

Here's how I get the variables and send them to the database :

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') 
    {   
    ////////// PROTECTION DES DONNEES ENVOYEES //////////
    $coupon = htmlspecialchars(addslashes($_POST['coupon']));
    $agence = htmlspecialchars(addslashes($_POST['agence']));
    $nom = htmlspecialchars(addslashes($_POST['nom']));
    $prenom = htmlspecialchars(addslashes($_POST['prenom']));
    $email = htmlspecialchars(addslashes($_POST['email']));
    $telephone = htmlspecialchars(addslashes($_POST['telephone']));
    $adresse = htmlspecialchars(addslashes($_POST['adresse']));
    $cpostal = htmlspecialchars(addslashes($_POST['cpostal']));
    $ville = htmlspecialchars(addslashes($_POST['ville']));
    $lieu = htmlspecialchars(addslashes($_POST['lieu']));

    die(var_dump($_POST));

        // ENVOI A LA BDD
        $sql = "INSERT INTO tui_inscription (id, coupon, agence, nom, prenom, email, telephone, adresse, cpostal, ville, lieu) ";
        $sql .= "VALUES('', '".$coupon."', '".$agence."', '".$nom."', '".$prenom."', '".$email."', '".$telephone."', '".$adresse."', '".$cpostal."', '".$ville."', '".$lieu."')";
        $sql_add = mysqli_query($connexion, $sql) 
            or die ("Impossible de finaliser l'inscription");
    }
```

Here's a var_dump($_POST) after sending the form :

```
array(10) { ["coupon"]=> string(8) "VIPTDO17" ["agence"]=> string(4) "Lyon" ["nom"]=> string(6) "MYNAME" ["prenom"]=> string(9) "MYSURNAME" ["email"]=> string(15) "email@gmail.com" ["telephone"]=> string(10) "0123456789" ["adresse"]=> string(10) "MY ADDRESS" ["cpostal"]=> string(5) "69007" ["ville"]=> string(4) "TOWN" ["lieu"]=> string(0) "" }
```

They all marked as Undefined Index error in the logs !

Please let me know what further information you need to help me.

Comment: You should post all relevant code, otherwise your question stands to get closed with this one [PHP: “Notice: Undefined variable”, “Notice: Undefined index”, and “Notice: Undefined offset”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Comment: ok, I'll do that... but it's french :)

Comment: No problem, just as long as the syntax remains the same ;-) I can understand it fully.

Comment: You should re-edit to include the HTML for it, seeing you're using a form for the POST arrays. My guess is that the input for "coupon", doesn't have a name attribute for it, or is written as `Coupon` maybe. I can't say for sure, because I don't know what the HTML is.

Comment: I thought about it, but input are all well named.
And it works perfectly on my server.
Could it be a PHP config problem ?

Comment: Plus, the errors probably stem from the `value="<?php echo $_POST['XXX']; ?>"`'s since they're not defined. You need to use a ternary operator for those.

Comment: The above ^ is most likely your solution here. On your other server, error reporting must have been disabled, that's why you are now getting errors/notices. You need to test again every POST array to check if they are not empty or use a ternary operator in the values in the form elements.

Comment: Shame on me... You're totally right :( I was expecting the errors to come from the treatment... I don't get anymore Undefined Error, but the SQL request still die()

Comment: Most probably you are getting these notices when the form is first loaded. Because, nothing has been posted yet. Once the data is posted, there should be no such notice.

Comment: *"but the SQL request still die()"* - You need to use `mysqli_error($connexion)` on the query to tell what exactly went wrong. @GrégorySantana instead of `or die ("Impossible de finaliser l'inscription")` - probably an sql injection or something else, depending on the data going in. And `"TOWN" ["lieu"]=> string(0) ""` looks to be empty here, probably why, because of `name="lieu" value="<?php echo strtolower($_POST['id']);?>"` being the wrong POST array.

Comment: **The answer is simple** You developed your site with error reporting **turned off**. So you didnt see all the errors in your site. When you moved to the IIS site it has error repoting **turned ON** and now you see all the errors!

Comment: Go back to your development server and **turn error reporting ON** and you will see them all on that server as well. **Thats the purpose of a development server**

Comment: Found it ! Thanks for your precious help !

Comment: So I assume you are going to turn error reporting off in the IIS server as well? **Great - Wrong choise**

Comment: Of course not... I fixed the errors and reactivated error logs on my server instead. I can't remember why they where off.